# How can I bind Collection from model to view MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing a web app using ASP.NET MVC, I have two entities like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Entity1 : IEntity<int>
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="list")]
    public ICollection Entity2Collection {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Entity2 : IEntity<int>
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="entity3id")]
    public int Entity3ObjId {get; set;}

    public Entity3 Entity3Obj {get; set;}
}
```

And in the controller action I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Entity1 entity)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid){
       await repository.updateAsync(entity);
    }
    return View();
}
```

In the entity parameter, the property **Entity2Collection** is always null, I don't know what I am missing because I have this in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Entity2Collection)
```

But it always null when I do a Post request. I hope for a little help.

Comment: where is the code showing how and where you set the values in Entity1.Entity2Collection ?

Comment: Where and how I must set the value in the entity.Entity2Collection is what i need to know. If I use Knockout viewmodel I have to declare a property named "list" as the DataMember indicate in the Entity1 model. But if i don't use Knockout viewmodels how I must do it?? this is the problem I am facing.

Comment: that has to be done inside the action

Comment: In case of Entity2 is a Collection you might have to run a loop in your view

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor() creates a hidden input for the object you pass to it.  So if you are passing it a list, you have to create the list before passing it.

Comment: Do you mean in the Edit action but when using Get request not in the Post  Edit Action.

Comment: But when I put DataMember Attribute in the model it suposes that it will serialize it as an empty array or not ??

Comment: Are you creating the new Entity1 record in the form or editing it there? You will need to create your collection (or grab an existing collection from somewhere) and set it as the value for that item before trying to use it in your @Html.HiddenFor() helper.  See the link posted by @krilovich for an example.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the parameter in the controller has to be the same as the name of the field, so you must name your field entity if that is what is in the controller

Also look at the following blog which shows how model binding with complex objects works in MVC

http://blog.codeinside.eu/2012/09/17/modelbinding-with-complex-objects-in-asp-net-mvc/